# AngularJS - How to make radio group as required fields inside a ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-repeat which I am using to repeat my JSON data to create Yes/No radio button group on a set of questions.

My $scope.RadioData has the following JSON data:

```
{
QuestionCd: "Q1"
QuestionTxt: "Some text for the question 1."
ResponseInd: ""
},
{
QuestionCd: "Q2"
QuestionTxt: "Some text for the question 2."
ResponseInd: ""
},
{
QuestionCd: "Q3"
QuestionTxt: "Some text for the question 3."
ResponseInd: ""
},
{
QuestionCd: "Q4"
QuestionTxt: "Some text for the question 4."
ResponseInd: ""
},
{
QuestionCd: "Q5"
QuestionTxt: "Some text for the question 5."
ResponseInd: ""
}
```

And my HTML is as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="radiodata in RadioData" ng-form="RadioForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="QuestionTxt" class="col-md-9 radio-inline">
            {{radiodata.QuestionTxt}}
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div ng-class="{ 'has-error' : RadioForm.{{radiodata.QuestionCd}}.$invalid }" class="has-error">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="{{radiodata.QuestionCd}}"
                            value="T" ng-model="radiodata.ResponseInd" required/>
                    Yes
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="{{radiodata.QuestionCd}}"
                            value="F" ng-model="QuestionRemarksData.ResponseInd" required/>
                    No
                </label>
                <span ng-show="RadioForm.{{radiodata.QuestionCd}}.$invalid" class="help-block">Required Field !</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My rendered HTML looks like this:

```
Some text for the question 1.      o Yes   o No
Some text for the question 2.      o Yes   o No
Some text for the question 3.      o Yes   o No
Some text for the question 4.      o Yes   o No
Some text for the question 5.      o Yes   o No

[Submit Button]
```

I have added the 'required' attribute to each radio button, but I am not able to make these radio buttons behave as required. If I have radio group outside ng-repeat, the same code makes it required.

So, how to make these set of questions with radio groups required inside ng-repeat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try using `ng-required="true"` instead of the html5 `required` attribute?

```
<div ng-repeat="radiodata in RadioData" ng-form="RadioForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="QuestionTxt" class="col-md-9 radio-inline">
            {{radiodata.QuestionTxt}}
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div ng-class="{ 'has-error' : RadioForm.{{radiodata.QuestionCd}}.$invalid }" class="has-error">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="{{radiodata.QuestionCd}}"
                            value="T" ng-model="radiodata.ResponseInd" ng-required="true"/>
                    Yes
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="{{radiodata.QuestionCd}}"
                            value="F" ng-model="QuestionRemarksData.ResponseInd" ng-required="true"/>
                    No
                </label>
                <span ng-show="RadioForm.{{radiodata.QuestionCd}}.$invalid" class="help-block">Required Field !</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, as a note, I seem to remember needing to add an `ng-click` to each option too, to prevent having to click the radio button twice to clear the error...

Answer (score 0):

Having exactly the same problem, and kind of getting crazy with it, this is what I found (pretty new to angularjs so might be I'm making big mistakes):

After doing some tests found that

```
<span ng-show="RadioForm.{{radiodata.QuestionCd}}.$invalid" 
  class="help-block">Required Field !</span>
```

Is always hiding, tried to log to the console, RadioForm.{{radiodata.QuestionCd}}.$invalid and is telling me

> $invalid not available in 'undefined'

So I guess the big problem here is how to ask for the 'component status' in the
radio form,  seems they are not recognized simply by the name.

I took a look in JS debugger and a very strange thing appear in the radioForm element
it has a "{{radioData.QuestionCd}}" (written exactly that way) as a property, I
might be missing something important here (clearly don't understand this last thing)

Not of much help, but may be this gives some other clue to someone

Comment: Found a *dirty solution*: Put the radio-group (all the radio inputs) inside ng-form, and then just ask for ng-form.$invalid, so you don't need to use fieldName between the form and the $invalid